# Navigate to file share created by Terraform in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

What specific syntax should we use to navigate to the file share directory created by the Terraform code below when we putty in to a RHEL virtual machine in the same resource group?

##### Form Of Answer Requested:

This OP is asking for an answer with a few lines of code in a form that looks something like:

```
ls -al sharename/example
mkdir sharename/example/newdirectory
cd sharename/example/newdirectory
ls -al
```

Also, we are asking if any additional resources need to be created in order for there to be storage that can be used by a VM that has permissions to use the storage share directory.

##### Terraform Code That Creates The Storage:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "azureteststorage"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.my-resources.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.my-resources.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "sharename"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "example" {
  name                 = "example"
  share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.example.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
}
```

Comment: may i know if the file share is mounted to the RHEL VM or not ? if mounted then how is it mounted ? can you add that mount commands used to the OP?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT This OP is asking you for the mount commands.  ...  Please assume we are starting from scratch here and the OP is all that there is.  ...  How would you resolve the problem?

Comment: Sure . let me provide you the possible solutions for the same

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

**There are multiple ways to configure the usage of File Share from a Azure VM .**

**Scenario 1 :** You can create share and VM at the same time and mount the Share using `remote_exec` on the VM like below :

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "aks-nfs-public-ip" {
  name                = "aks-nfs-public-ip"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"

}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-nsg"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.aks-nfs-public-ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.example
  ]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "ansuazureteststorage1"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "ansushare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "example" {
  name                 = "example"
  share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.example.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_ssh_public_key" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-sshkey"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  public_key          = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_D4s_v4"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "Password@1234"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]
  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
    admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = azurerm_ssh_public_key.example.public_key
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "RedHat"
    offer     = "RHEL"
    sku       = "82gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
 
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = azurerm_public_ip.aks-nfs-public-ip.ip_address
      user        = "adminuser"
      password    = "Password@1234"
    }
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "sudo yum install cifs-utils -y",
        "sudo mkdir -p /mnt/${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}/${azurerm_storage_share.example.name}",
        "sudo mount -t cifs //${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}.file.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_share.example.name} /mnt/${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}/${azurerm_storage_share.example.name} -o vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,username=${azurerm_storage_account.example.name},password=${azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key}",
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**Scenario-2 :** If you have an existing VM then you can just create the storage resources and then using `custom script extension` you can mount them :

***terraform code :***

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "ansuazureteststorage1"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "ansushare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "example" {
  name                 = "example"
  share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.example.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
}

data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "MountShare"
 virtual_machine_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "script": "${base64encode(templatefile("customdata.sh", {
          Storage_account_name="${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}", 
          File_share_name="${azurerm_storage_share.example.name}", 
          Storage_account_key = "${azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key}"
        }))}"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

***customdata.sh:***

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo yum install cifs-utils -y
sudo mkdir -p "/mnt/${Storage_account_name}/${File_share_name}"
sudo mount -t cifs "//${Storage_account_name}.file.core.windows.net/${File_share_name}" "/mnt/${Storage_account_name}/${File_share_name}" -o "vers=3.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,username=${Storage_account_name},password=${Storage_account_key}"
```

**Output :**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Scenario - 3 : If you want to use putty to ssh and then mount you can just `go to>>Portal>>share that you created from terraform >> Connect >> Linux and copy the script provided there and run in the VM after doing putty`:

[image]

Comment: How do you recommend storing executables and scripts that require a lot of disk storage space?  We keep testing higher and higher virtual machine SKUs, up to `Standard_DS6_v2` so far, but so far they all have only 1 GB of on-machine disk storage, which means that all of the VMs we have tried so far throw **disk full** errors when we try to provision them.  What is more, the file share created using your answer gives a different error saying we are not allowed to make files in file shares executable.

Comment: @CodeMed, DS series offer less temp storage as compared to D series . you can check for 
[Memory optimized Dv2 and Dsv2-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series-memory) for higher disk space  . if you don't want such higher memory then you can check the [Dv2 series general Purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series) .